# how to pass authentication/credentials to the google cloud api post that I'm running from python

Tags: python, post, get, google-cloud-platform

I don't know how to pass authentication/credentials to the google cloud api post that I'm running from my python program

```
import requests

api_endpoint = "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/projectid/templates"


data = {
  "jobName": "scriptjob2",
  "parameters": {
    "inputFilePattern": "gs://bucket/files/*.json",
    "outputTopic": "projects/project6/topics/data"
  },
  "environment": {
    "tempLocation": "gs://bucket/tmp",
    "zone": "us-central1-f"
  },
  "gcsPath": "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub",
  "location": "us-central1"
}

r = requests.post(url = api_endpoint, data = data)

result = r.text
print("Result:%s"%result)
```

I know that I'm supposed to pass a google service account authentication but I just can't figure out how to do this. This is the error message that I'm getting.

```
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other v

alid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the sdk for python for dataflow.

However, if you insist on using requests, it's as simple as:

```
"https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/projectid/templates&key={yourapikey}"
```

[here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/dataflow/dataflow/v1b3/dataflow.projects.templates.create) is a link to this in the browser for you to test with.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your suggestion pointed me into the right direction. I was able to get this working via python sdk.

Answer (score 1):

This is how was I was able to get this to work:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)


PROJECT = 'projectid'
BUCKET = 'dataflow-templates'
TEMPLATE = 'GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub'
GCSPATH="gs://{bucket}/latest/{template}".format(bucket=BUCKET, template=TEMPLATE)
BODY = {
   "jobName": "job1",
   "parameters": {
       "inputFilePattern": "gs://bucket/files/*.json",
       "outputTopic": "projects/project6/topics/data"
   },
   "environment": {
       "tempLocation": "gs://bucket/tmp",
       "zone": "us-central1-f"
   }
}


request = service.projects().templates().launch(projectId=PROJECT, gcsPath=GCSPATH, body=BODY)
response = request.execute()

print(response)
```